# Possible to manually set parameters in linear model and get R Squared, etc?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am solving a linear model with bounds on the parameters.  The simple statsmodels OLS method doesn't allow for bounds on the fitted parameters, so to do this, I maximize a likelihood function using scipy.optimize.minimize.  From this, I have my set of parameters for a linear model.  All good so far.

All I need to acheive now is to be able to access statistics for my model, such as R^2, F-Stat, etc.  For an OLS, these things all come with the object returned by model.fit() along with other nice features.

I'm wondering if it is possible to create this object, manually assign my parameters from the bounded fit, and have it compute the data fields on the fit result object? Obviously, I could just manually compute these things but I want it such that whether I am calling for a bounded or unbounded fit, I get the same object type returned and life is easy downstream.

## Pseudo code:

```
bounded_params = fitBoundedLinear(x, y) # solution to bounded problem - a list of floats
model = statsmodels.api.OLS(y, x)
unbounded_fitResult = model.fit()       # solution to unbounded problem - a regression results object
```

want to do something like:

```
aFitResult.params = bounded_params  # manually set the parameters
aFitResult.calculate()              # force it to compute data fields based on these params
rsq = aFitResult.rsquared # etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something that works - but it is probably not an ideal solution:

aFitResult = statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper(statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(model, bounded_params))

Comment: looks fine to me. Subclassing OLS or regression models and overwriting fit might be cleaner. A possible problem, and one of the reason that inequality constraints have not been added, is that the inference is nonstandard, e.g. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1211

Comment: You're right ... creating a derived class and defining a fit() method to do the bounded fit would be the cleanest solution.  Thanks - and thanks for the link re nnls

Answer (score 0):

you can add upper_bound and lower_bound to  fit_elasticnet in elastic_net.py as:

```
def fit_elasticnet(model, method="coord_descent", maxiter=100,
         alpha=0., L1_wt=1., start_params=None, cnvrg_tol=1e-7,
         zero_tol=1e-8, refit=False, check_step=True,
         loglike_kwds=None, score_kwds=None, hess_kwds=None, upper_bound=None, lower_bound=None):
```

then inside that function after the following line:

```
params[k] = _opt_1d(func, grad, hess, model_1var, params[k], alpha[k]*L1_wt,
                                tol=btol, check_step=check_step)
```

add:

```
        if upper_bound is not None:
            params[k] = min(params[k], upper_bound[k])

        if lower_bound is not None:                
            params[k] = max(params[k], lower_bound[k])
```

then call the function similar to:

```
model = lm.OLS(y, x)
results_fu = model.fit()
#results_fu.summary()
results_fr = model.fit_regularized(alpha=0.001
                                   ,start_params=results_fu.params
                                   ,upper_bound=(.60,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
                                   ,lower_bound=(-1, 0,0,0,-1,1,1,1,-10) )
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The results are not within the upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Set the model's initial parameters to the desired values via `start_params=` and then fit them using `maxiter=0` to do a fit with 0 steps (i.e. don't fit, but still run through all the initialization and metric computation).

```py
result = model.fit(start_params=your_parameters_here, maxiter=0)
result.rsquared  # or any other fit index
```

Comment: When I tried, looks like these two input parameter have no effect on the result. I get the same result as if had not given any parameters in input at all (which agree it is strange)